# Order independent integer hashing?

Tags: rust, hash, set

I want to implement the `Hash` trait for a datatype that is defined as a list of integers and where the order does not matter.

So for example `{1, 2, 3} == {2, 1, 3}`.

I have this naive (and wrong) implementation atm:

```rs
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct PolytopeVertex(Vec<usize>);

impl Hash for PolytopeVertex
{
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H)
    {
        let mut res = 1;
        for i in &self.0
        {
            res *= i;
        }
        res.hash(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Also this implementation is definitely not wrong. It upholds the contract of `Hash::hash`.

Comment: @cdhowie This implementation is wrong because different keys will produce the same hash even when distinct, for example:

{6} and {1,2,3} produce the same hash, same issue with {1, N} and {N} for any N. The question is how to achieve a hash that is unique as per the numbers in the set without ordering as stated.

Comment: @Makogan: *"This implementation is wrong because different keys will produce the same hash even when distinct,"* - a requirement of a hash is not that different input produces always different output, only that the probability for this is small and ideally evenly distributed over the output space.

Comment: And the probability in this case is not small, whatsoever.

Comment: The contract for a hash is only that `x == y` implies `hash(x) == hash(y)`, and that's it. Everything else depends on how you want to use the hash, and on the statistical properties of your data. Without this information, we can't help.

Comment: @Makogan: this is less a programming question but more a question on how to choose the right algorithms for the specific kind of data distribution you have. I recommend that you abstract away the problem from the actual programming language but instead fokus on what kind of input data you have and what you expect from the output - then ask at [math.se] or [stats.se] for help.

Comment: A simple way of inheriting many of the properties of an underlying hash is using `hash(x_1) xor hash(x_2) xor … xor hash(x_n)`.

Comment: You can do `.sort` on `Vec<usize>` and then `sorted_vec.hash(state)`.

Comment: You can achieve order-independent hashing by sorting the data first and then hashing the sorted data with *any* hash function. Another alternative is to use any binary operation B(x,y) that is computer-commutative: B(x,y)=B(y,x). That is the approach you've taken with your example.

Comment: How many integers are we talking about? A `Vec` may be unbounded in principle, but could it be that in your case it's always small? (This changes the _cost_ of upfront operations such as sorting, drastically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This implementation is wrong because different keys will produce the same hash even when distinct, for example: {6} and {1,2,3} produce the same hash, same issue with {1, N} and {N} for any N.

Any hashing algorithm will *always* have collisions. This is something that you *should* expect.

Furthermore, any "pre-compression" of the entropy (in your case, going from `Vec<usize>` to `usize`) will *also* have collisions *before* the hash algorithm comes into play... so is typically best avoided.

---

Ideally, you would look for an order-independent hashing algorithm, and use that instead. This would give you the best performance & quality at the same time. Unfortunately, I have no idea whether a *good* such algorithm exists.

From a *quality* point of view, sorting before hashing would give order independence. This is by design, since it just means that your hashing algorithm sees the same sequence as your equality algorithm. Unfortunately, for large-ish vectors performance will suffer. A "counting" sort may help, but only if there are many duplicates.

From a *performance* point of view, and at the cost of a quality degradation, implementing a *naive* hash first (pre-compression) is possible, we just need to remember two things:

- You want to push the *length* of the vector in that calculation.
- You want to push *something* in between elements.

This will help in avoiding the conflation scenarios you describe.

---

So, a terrible hash function, but still better than the current one you have:

```rust
impl Hash for PolytopeVertex {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        const SEPARATOR: u64 = 1_099_511_628_211; // Large prime lifted from FNV.

        //  If empty, 0 is not problematic.
        let mut result = self.0.len() as u64;

        //  Wrapping multiplication is commutative, hence order-independent.
        for i in &self.0 {
            result.wrapping_mul(i as u64);
            result.wrapping_mul(SEPARATOR);
        }

        result.hash(state);
    }
}
```

This will neatly avoid the {6} vs {1, 2, 3} conflation.

It does, still, suffer from the fact that `0` is a black-hole, should the sequence of multiplications ever lead to a multiple of 2<sup>64</sup>, the hash will always be 0. This is trivially achieved by having `(1 << 63)` twice in the vector.

Comment: For a cryptographic underlying hash, simply xor'ing the hashes of all integers together is fine (and again a cryptographic hash), and faster than sorting first. I haven't posted an answer since I haven't heard any requirements for the has from the OP yet, so I thought answering was kind of moot.